# Notification upon editing comment

Tags: feature-request, comment, comment-replies

The following situation has happened to me several times: Someone writes a comment tagging me with the @, I read the comment, and shortly after the comment is edited in such a way that the nature of the comment is completely changed, after which I see it maybe an hour later if at all. I would bet that there are at least a few that I have missed completely. I've observed that the situation has also happened at least once in reverse (I edited a comment and the person didn't see the edit until I pointed it out).

Is it feasible to have a user that is tagged in a comment be notified whenever a comment they are tagged in is edited?

EDIT: Other methods of notification, even if it does not involve the pinging, would also be good, such as what happens when posts are edited or comments are added when you're on the page. This won't be visible on the android app, I assume, which is where I spend most of my site time, but it would fix the problem in the browser at least.

EDIT EDIT: has this been implemented? I think I just got notified in the android app when someone edited a comment. I got a ping but no new comment in the view, and I checked and the comment was edited.

Comment: As far as I know, you are notified if a question you have "favorited" is notified. I don't think this happens for comments.

Comment: FWIW: This is the behavior that exists in chat for `@` pings.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is it a typo and you wanted to write *is modified* instead of *is notified*? (I know that moderators can edit comments, so you can correct the typo, if it is one. Feel free to remove my comment after you have seen it.) Somewhat ironically, the OP will not be notified that you have edited your comment.

Comment: [Global inbox message not updated after comment edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66766/global-inbox-message-not-updated-after-comment-edit) at meta.SE is marked ([meta-tag:status-bydesign]). (Maybe it is not exactly the same, but it is certainly similar.)

Comment: I agree, it's painfully annoying in some cases. I doubt it will be fixed though, considering the thread Martin linked. Maybe a different suggestion, like having some javascript telling you that the comment has been edited (like there is for qiestions and answers) would be doable?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: When you look at a page and a question/answer is edited, a little box pops up to tell you that, and you can click on it to refresh the question/answer. There could be something similar for comments (there are probably performance issues though, there are in general considerably more comments than posts, so if you need to poll something all the time for each of them... I don't know)

Comment: I could see repeated pings being annoying (I often find myself correcting a comment a few times; I'd hate to ping someone 9 times). But that could be circumvented: get pinged once when the comment is posted, and again, if edited, after the 5 minutes have passed and the comment is "finalized".